# In my LinkedList, head_pop() and append() take the same time?

Tags: python, data-structures, linked-list

I want to test if delete a LinkList's head element fast than add an element to LinkList's end.

This is my LinkList's main code:

```
class LNode:
    def __init__(self,elem,next_=None):
        self.elem=elem
        self.next=next_

class LinkList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.__head=None

    #delete head element
    def head_pop(self):
        if self.__head is None:
            raise LinkedListUnderflow("in pop")
        e=self.__head.elem
        self.__head=self.__head.next
        return e

    #add an element at end
    def append(self,elem):
        if self.__head is None:
            self.__head=LNode(elem)
            return
        p=self.__head
        while p.next is not None:
            p=p.next
        p.next=LNode(elem)

import time

#test time
def timetest(f):
    start=time.clock()
    for a in range(0,1000000):
        f
    end=time.clock()
    print("times:"+str(end-start))
```

then,I try this:

```
llist=LinkList()

def append():
    llist.append(666)

def head_pop():
    llist.head_pop()

timetest(append())
timetest(head_pop())
```

Output:

```
times:0.029582597002445254
times:0.03032071299821837
```

As you can see, they cost same time.

But I think it should be O(n):O(1).

Comment: Your `timetest` isn't doing what you think it is doing. You *call* the function, then pass the result to `timetest`, when you probably meant to pass the function. But even given that, in `timetest` you merely *reference* the variable, e.g. `f`, but you need to *call it*, e.g. `f()`

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is passing the result of `append()` to your time test function, whereas you want to pass the function itself!

Change your time-test to call the `f` function:

```
def timetest(f):
    start=time.clock()
    for a in range(0,1000000):
        f() # <- note the () here
    end=time.clock()
    print("times:"+str(end-start))
```

Then use this to test:

```
timetest(append)
timetest(head_pop)
```

As you can see, we're passing in the function for the test to call, instead of the RESULT of the function (being called once!)